# Changing structure of database and moving data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration

My Database has entities `Driver` and `DriverWork` like this:

**Edited:**

```
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DriverWork
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FromLocation { get; set; }

    public string ToLocation { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

And contains many rows in those entities. Now I've added another Entity with name `WorkPage`, which changes relation from this:

`DriverWork --> Driver`

To this:

`DriverWork --> WorkPage --> Driver`

Models after the change (`Driver` is still the old one):

```
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class WorkPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte CommissionPercentage { get; set; }

    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class DriverWork
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FromLocation { get; set; }

    public string ToLocation { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int WorkPageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WorkPageId))]
    public WorkPage WorkPage { get; set; }
}
```

After adding a new migration, I knew that I should make changes in the `Up` method because some drivers currently don't have any `WorkPage`s and I should at least add one `WorkPage` for them, also current `DriverWork` items must change their `DriverId` value to a valid `WorkPageId` that is associated with that `Driver`. But I don't know how should I do this migration in EF6?

Without making any changes in `Up` method, EF gives this error after running `update-database` command:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.DriverWorks_dbo.WorkPages_WorkPageId". The conflict occurred in database "{dblocation}\KHORSHIDDATA.MDF", table "dbo.WorkPages", column 'Id'.
```

Any help?

Comment: Tough task. Do you have other columns in `DriverWork` and `WorkPage` tables?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, 3 other columns in `WorkPage` and 4 other columns in `DriverWork`. I did not state them in the question.

Comment: Can you add them? Because I'm thinking in rename table + create new table + insert some data direction.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sine it's a tough transformation, I would suggest performing it with two passes.

First, keep the `DriverId` FK in the `DriverWork` and make `DriverId` in `WorkPage` optional (nullable):

```
public class WorkPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte CommissionPercentage { get; set; }

    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }

    public int? DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class DriverWork
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FromLocation { get; set; }

    public string ToLocation { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public int WorkPageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WorkPageId))]
    public WorkPage WorkPage { get; set; }
}
```

Generate new migration. It should be something like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.WorkPage",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                CommissionPercentage = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                IsClosed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                DateClosed = c.DateTime(),
                DriverId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Driver", t => t.DriverId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.DriverId);

    AddColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPage", "Id");
}
```

Execute the migration. Then restore the desired entity model by removing the `Driver` from `DriverWork` and making `DriverId` in `WorkPage` required (non null):

```
public class WorkPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte CommissionPercentage { get; set; }

    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class DriverWork
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FromLocation { get; set; }

    public string ToLocation { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int WorkPageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WorkPageId))]
    public WorkPage WorkPage { get; set; }
}
```

Generate a second new migration. It should look something like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "DriverId", "dbo.Driver");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPages");
    DropIndex("dbo.DriverWork", new[] { "DriverId" });
    DropIndex("dbo.DriverWork", new[] { "WorkPageId" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPage", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "DriverId");
}
```

Use `Sql` methods to populate the `WorkPage` table data and update the `WorkTableId` FK before making it required. For instance, insert the following at the beginning of the `Up` method:

```
Sql(@"insert into dbo.WorkPage (CommissionPercentage, IsClosed, DateClosed, DriverId) select 0, 0, null, DriverId from dbo.DriverWork");
Sql(@"update dbo.DriverWork set WorkPageId = WP.Id from dbo.DriverWork DW join dbo.WorkPage WP on DW.DriverId = WP.DriverId");
```

Execute the migration and you are done.

Actually the `Sql` calls which transform the data can be at the end of the first migration `Up` method.

Knowing all that in advance, you can keep your new model as is (skip the first step) and simply replace the generated migration `Up` method with the union of the above two, e.g.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.WorkPage",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                CommissionPercentage = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                IsClosed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                DateClosed = c.DateTime(),
                DriverId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Driver", t => t.DriverId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.DriverId);

    AddColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPage", "Id");

    Sql(@"insert into dbo.WorkPage (CommissionPercentage, IsClosed, DateClosed, DriverId) select 0, 0, null, DriverId from dbo.DriverWork");
    Sql(@"update dbo.DriverWork set WorkPageId = WP.Id from dbo.DriverWork DW join dbo.WorkPage WP on DW.DriverId = WP.DriverId");

    DropForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "DriverId", "dbo.Driver");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPages");
    DropIndex("dbo.DriverWork", new[] { "DriverId" });
    DropIndex("dbo.DriverWork", new[] { "WorkPageId" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", "dbo.WorkPage", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "DriverId");
}
```

Comment: I've generated the first migration and it is like yours. But after `update-database` it gives the same error: `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.DriverWorks_dbo.WorkPages_WorkPageId". The conflict occurred in database "{dblocation}\KHORSHIDDATA.MDF", table "dbo.WorkPages", column 'Id'.`

Comment: Looks like you didn't make the `WorkPageId` column initially nullable as suggested? Check this line `AddColumn("dbo.DriverWork", "WorkPageId", c => c.Int());`, it shouldn't contain `nullable: false`